# JRadioButton needs a click after selection in order for ActionListener to take effect

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm currently working on a GUI where if the user clicks the "Yes" JRadioButton a JTextField appears and if they click "No" the JTextField disappears. I'm having an issue where even if the "Yes" button is clicked, the JTextField only appears if the user clicks somewhere in the GUI.

Here's my ActionListener

```
public void setPanelSpecifications(){

    txtCognosModelNames.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    txtCognosModelNames.setLineWrap(true);
    txtCognosModelReview.setVisible(false);
    btnNoCognosModel.setSelected(true);

    btnYesCognosModel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
            txtCognosModelReview.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    btnNoCognosModel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            txtCognosModelReview.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

[Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqK3e.png)

[After clicking yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLVlo.png)

[After clicking in GUI and Yes selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYnhS.png)

Comment: You're forgetting to call `revalidate()` -- which tells the layout managers to re-layout components, and then `repaint()` to repaint the container and its contents. Better still though is to use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to swap views, here swapping a JTextField with say an empty JLabel.

Comment: Thanks! The panel is a bit more complex than the pictures I have provided but I'll definitely look into the CardLayout. Thanks again, you're awesome 

Comment: Another option -- show the JTextField but enable/disable it depending on the radiobutton's state. Simply call `txtCognosModelReview.setEnabled(...)` within the listener

Comment: Good call, much cleaner too.